# ¿Comó dividir una columna en múltiples columnas?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Tengo un data.frame que contiene todos los datos en una sola columna, y necesito que esos datos llenen mi data.frame. Necesito dividirlos por medio de `|` pero no he tenido éxito.

He utilizado

```
Tranformar_en_R <- Tranformar_en_R %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, str_replace_all, "|", ",")
```

```
Tranformar_en_R <- str_split_fixed(Tranformar_en_R$Prop_0, '|', n=Inf)
```

¿Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero dividir la columna, como se hace en excel, por medio del `|`

Answer (score 2):

Existe una función llamada `separate()` de la libreria `tidyr` que hace lo que buscas:

Digamos tenemos el siguiente df de ejemplo:

```
df = data.frame(Var_1 = paste0(letters[1:5], "|", LETTERS[1:5], "|", 1:5))
```

df

```
  Var_1
1 a|A|1
2 b|B|2
3 c|C|3
4 d|D|4
5 e|E|5
```

podemos hacer:

```
df %>% separate(
  col = Var_1,                    # nombre de la columna a separar
  into = c("Min", "May", "num"),  # nombres de las columnas a crear
  sep = "\\|" ,                   # patron a buscar, en este caso se usa \\ por ser un caracter especial
  remove = T                      # sirve para conservar la variable a separar
)
```

output:

```
  Min May num
1   a   A   1
2   b   B   2
3   c   C   3
4   d   D   4
5   e   E   5
```